# '[object Object]' error in onesignal notification for firefox

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, onesignal

I developed notifications for a website using onesignal API. It works fine with all supported browsers but in case mozilla firefox, the content/text of message doesn't apppear. Instead [object Object] appears in place of the text. This is just the case with firefox, with other browsers the text does appear. Why is it so? & how to resolve this?

Comment: Please add some code if possible.

Comment: Provide code, may be try using JSON.stringify.

Comment: never mind found the solution. I did use JSON.stringify.